# Notepad++ regexp increase number

Tags: mysql, regex, notepad++, phpbb3

We've got an old PhPBB3 installation with a lot of posts in it. We've made a new installation which already contains new posts. What i want to do, is export the MySQL to XML from the old installation, reset post_id and topic_id to the following number of the new installation.
We will put everything in 1 new category (import, 111).

```
            <column name="post_id">3</column>
        <column name="topic_id">3</column>
```

The new columns are running in 3000, lets say 3337.
So what i need is every line that has

```
<column name="post_id">3</column>
```

Needs to get

```
<column name="post_id">3338</column>
```

Same goes for topic_id...
How would one do this?

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to update the post_id directly in the old MySQL (or in a copy of the old MySQL) BEFORE exporting it?

Comment: Regex can't increase numbers, you will have to update in MySQL or parse your xml and update it there.

Comment: Look at https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=65&t=1917165 HTH

Comment: Before the Ruby, i will go with the phpbb community merge =)

Comment: @OlafDietsche if you can create a answer, i can +1 it =)

Comment: @Tuumke It's just a link, nothing more. If it helped, +1 the comment. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with Ruby, Python or Perl. Here's how it's done in Ruby:

```
$ ruby -pi.bak -e '$_.gsub!(/(<column name="post_id">)(\d+)(<\/column>)/) { "#{$1}#{$2.to_i + 3000}#{$3}" }' file.xml
```

Your `file.xml` will be edited in-place and the backup copy will be saved to `file.xml.bak`.

Comment: And this could not be done with notepad++? =(
Then i must install ruby and have a look at that =(

Comment: @Tuumke, I've never used Notepad++, but I'm almost certain that it doesn't have any advanced evaluation inside its search and replace functionality. Most editors don't. Normal regular expressions don't support arithmetic operations. Why is it so important to do it from within the editor? Use the best tool for the job.